# get printed data by calling javascript of mongo in Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm using Java, I've written a script of MongoDB, which uses by loadServerScripts() 
the script prints a lot data.
I'd like to get all these data saved into mysql
I've no idea of ruby or perl or python, but resolution with them will be all right too.

btw I don't know how to install pymongo.

Comment: are you asking for migration of mongodb data to mysql ?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to resolve this :

1. **Non-Programmatic way**.

   - Use [mongoexport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) to get the data out of `system.js` collection in CVS format.
   - Then you can directly import that into MySQL. (not sure why this is required though). [This](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2345/import_csv_file_directly_into_mysql/) could be of help.
2. **Programmatic way in Java**.

   - Using the Java driver execute `db.system.js.find()`
   - The DbObjects can be traversed and then saved into MySQL db using JDBC. Alternatively if you are using Spring Data, the retrieval and saving of data would be a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

You want the printed output of the scripts to be stored in MySQL?

1) Run eval and pipe to a file, parse and then somehow store in MySQL

```
mongo --eval "db.loadServerScripts(); myScript();" > script_output.txt
```

2) Why not convert the js scripts to a programming language that you are familiar with and then run the commands - and also insert into MySQL.

To install pymongo - see the documentation: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/installation.html

Comment: `db.loadServerScripts` does not print anything. So not sure what you would be writing to file.

Comment: Just going on what @Kevin said - "I've written a script of MongoDB, which uses by loadServerScripts() the script prints a lot data"  He can call the relevant script / function - will update